# How to use like query without any where conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tasks t 
                     LEFT JOIN users u 
                     ON t.allowed_countries LIKE u.country");
```

Comment: there is not where conditions in your query.

Comment: You can't use LIKE clause in the ON clause of a JOIN query

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  SQL has not requirement of a `where` clause for queries.

Comment: @apomene Yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear what your intent is but the query 'works'

```
drop table if exists t,t1;
create table t(allowed_countries varchar(3));
create table t1(country varchar(3));
insert into t values ('uk'),('usa');
insert into t1 values ('uk'),('us');

SELECT * FROM  t 
LEFT JOIN t1 u 
ON t.allowed_countries LIKE u.country ;

+-------------------+---------+
| allowed_countries | country |
+-------------------+---------+
| uk                | uk      |
| usa               | NULL    |
+-------------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Perhaps you want to include Wildcards(%)?

```
SELECT * FROM  t 
LEFT JOIN t1 u 
ON t.allowed_countries LIKE concat(u.country,'%') ;

+-------------------+---------+
| allowed_countries | country |
+-------------------+---------+
| uk                | uk      |
| usa               | us      |
+-------------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT 'ABC' AS my_col UNION ALL
  SELECT 'CDE' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ABCDE'
)
SELECT a.my_col, b.my_col
FROM cte1 a
INNER JOIN cte1 b ON a.my_col LIKE CONCAT('%', b.my_col, '%');
```

In your case, that would translate to something like:

```
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tasks t 
                     LEFT JOIN users u 
                     ON t.allowed_countries LIKE CONCAT('%', u.country, '%') ");
```

[SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pcqHewgbR4XNnNoQVVXAg1/3)

Comment: CTEs (with) come in on version 8.0

Answer (score 0):

that should work if the data will meet the values you wanted.

`$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tasks t LEFT JOIN users u ON t.allowed_countries LIKE '%u.country%');`